# SQL statement to select from two tables with where

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables defined as follow:

**Courses**

```
course ID     course Name
1             Math
2             Science
3             geography
```

and another table (its use is to show enrolled students in courses):

**student_courses**

```
course ID     student ID      Final cost
1             2               100
2             3               200
```

I need a SQL statement that selects only the courses that a certain student (its value is a parameter from a control on my page -but that is not my problem) isn't enrolled in....

My latest try is this:

```
SELECT 
   Courses.[Course ID], Courses.[Course name] 
FROM 
   Courses, student_courses 
where 
   Courses.[Course ID] <> student_courses.[Course ID]
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**20 years** ago!). ***Please*** stop using it

Comment: what is your desired output ? you want to get the name of courses that no student have enrolled in ?

Comment: @Moiz no i want to get the course ID and course name of the courses that a specific student is not enrolled in........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT [Course ID], [Course name] 
FROM Courses
WHERE [Course ID] NOT IN 
 (SELECT Course ID from student_courses WHERE [student ID]=1)
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need something like this:

```
SELECT
    c.[Course ID], c.[Course Name]
FROM
    dbo.Course c
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.StudentCourses sc
                WHERE [Student ID] = 2 AND [Course ID] = c.[Course ID])
```

See [my SQL Fiddle showing this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d739d/3).

Basically, just select those courses that do not have an entry in `Student_Courses` with that `[Student ID]`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (Transact) SQL I can think of is this:

```
select 
     [courses].[course ID]
   , [courses].[course name]
from [courses]
left outer join [student_courses]  
       on   [student_courses].[course ID]  = [courses].[course ID] 
       and  [student_courses].[student ID] = @studentID
where 
     [student_courses].[student ID] is null
```

Don't put the "[student_courses].[student ID] = @studentID" in the where clause because this will cause the null values you're interested in to be thrown away and your left join will *look* like an inner join.

If you want to get unnecessarily complicated you could use group, having and count instead.

```
select 
    [courses].[course ID]
  , [courses].[course name]
from [courses]
left outer join [student_courses]  
           on   [student_courses].[course ID]  = [courses].[course ID] 
           and  [student_courses].[student ID] = @studentID
group by
     [courses].[course ID]
   , [courses].[course name]
having count([student_courses].[course ID]) = 0
```

It's probably a good idea to lose the spaces from column names. It'll only cause you trouble in the long term.